# Cleaning of JSON Objects using Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to clean my json file.I used RDD to read the Json file and then tried to clean it using replace function but still I am not getting the correct json file because of the escape sequences present in the JSON value.

Here is my code with which I am trying to clean the JSON file of various disturbances.
    The cleaned JSON shows errors.Please review and tell the issue**

```
  val readjson = sparkSession
                  .sparkContext.textFile("dev.json")




   val json=readjson.map(element=>element
         .replace("\"\":\"\"","\":\"")
         .replace("\"\",\"\"","\",\"")
         .replace("\"\":","\":")
         .replace(",\"\"",",\"")
         .replace("\"{\"\"","{\"")
         .replace("\"\"}\"","\"}"))
         .saveAsTextFile("JSON")
```

### HERE IS MY JSON FILE

---

```
"{""SEQ_NO"":596514,""PROV_DEMOG_SK"":596514,""PROV_ID"":""QMP000003370581"",""FRST_NM"":"""",""LAST_NM"":""RICHARD WHITTINGTON BUTCHER"",""FUL_NM"":"""",""GENDR_CD"":"""",""PROV_NPI"":"""",""PROV_STAT"":""Incomplete"",""PROV_TY"":""03"",""DT_OF_BRTH"":"""",""PROFPROFL_DESGTN"":"""",""ETL_LAST_UPDT_DT_TM"":""2020-04-28 11:43:31.000000"",""PROV_CLSFTN_CD"":""A"",""SRC_DATA_KEY"":50,""OPRN_CD"":""I"",""REC_SET"":""F""}"
```

I tried cleaning the above json and got the following result:-

```
{
    "SEQ_NO": 596514,
    "PROV_DEMOG_SK": 596514,
    "PROV_ID": "QMP000003370581",
    "FRST_NM": "",
    "LAST_NM": "RICHARD WHITTINGTON BUTCHER",
    "FUL_NM": "",
    "GENDR_CD": "",
    "PROV_NPI": "",
    "PROV_STAT": "Incomplete",
    "PROV_TY": "03",
    "DT_OF_BRTH": "",
    "PROFPROFL_DESGTN": "",
    "ETL_LAST_UPDT_DT_TM": "2020-04-28 11:43:31.000000",
    "PROV_CLSFTN_CD": "A",
    "SRC_DATA_KEY": 50,
    "OPRN_CD": "I",
    "REC_SET": "F"
}
```

The JSON validators present online show that it is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your JSON has one or few control character `\u0009` try replacing them with

```
.replaceAll("\\u0009"," ")
```

You can do it in below sequence

```
val replacedVal = """{""SEQ_NO"":596514,""PROV_DEMOG_SK"":596514,""PROV_ID"":""QMP000003370581"",""FRST_NM"":\"\"\"",""LAST_NM"":""RICHARD WHITTINGTON BUTCHER"",""FUL_NM"":\"\"\"",""GENDR_CD"":\"\"\"",""PROV_NPI"":\"\"\"",""PROV_STAT"":""Incomplete"",""PROV_TY"":""03"",""DT_OF_BRTH"":\"\"\"",""PROFPROFL_DESGTN"":\"\"\"",""ETL_LAST_UPDT_DT_TM"":""2020-04-28 11:43:31.000000"",""PROV_CLSFTN_CD"":""A"",""SRC_DATA_KEY"":50,""OPRN_CD"":""I"",""REC_SET"":""F""}"""
  .replace("""\"""",""""""")
  .replace("""""""",""""""")
  .replaceAll("\\u0009"," ")
```

Comment: Can you also help me in removing extra "" from values of JSON object    {"SEQ_NO":597216,"PROV_DEMOG_SK":597216,"PROV_ID":"QMP000003371283","FRST_NM":"","LAST_NM":"SMITH "LIBBY" MARY","FUL_NM":"","GENDR_CD":"","PROV_NPI":"","PROV_STAT":"Incomplete","PROV_TY":"03","DT_OF_BRTH":"","PROFPROFL_DESGTN":"","ETL_LAST_UPDT_DT_TM":"2020-04-28 11:43:31.000000","PROV_CLSFTN_CD":"A","SRC_DATA_KEY":50,"OPRN_CD":"I","REC_SET":"F"}
Here I am facing problem with removing extra "" from LAST_NM